# How to show updated date after an ajax call in Django

Tags: ajax, django

I'm trying to implement review section in my Django app. The below is my source code for posting and listing reviews of a store. I've already done creating a review with Ajax, but I can't figure out how to show the newly created review after the Ajax call.

Like how like button works in social media, I can easily update the like button based on the response of Ajax call by changing `attr()` or `html()`. But, this doesn't apply to this review case since it shows a store's reviews with for looping. So I feel like I gotta figure out how to let the for loop run again after the Ajax call.

Have anyone dones this before?

**HTML**

```
<div class="review-new">
  <div class="my-rating" name="rating"></div>    
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="ratingTextarea"></textarea>
  <input class="global-btn" stlye="float:right" type="button" value="Submit" id="review-submit"
  data-url="{% url 'boutique:post-review-api' store.domainKey %}" data-store-id="{{ store.id }}">
</div>

...

{% for i in store.review_set.all %}
  ...
{% endfor %}
```

**views.py**

```
class ReviewPost(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request, store_domainKey=None, format=None):

        rating = request.data['rating']
        content = request.data['content']
        store_id = request.data['storeId']
        store = Store.objects.get(id=store_id)

        new_review = Review()
        new_review.store = store
        new_review.review_score = rating
        new_review.content = content
        new_review.created_by = request.user
        new_review.save()

        reviews = store.review_set.all()
        data = {
            'reviews': reviews
        }
        return Response(data)
```

**ajax.js**

```
$(document).on("click", "#review-submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var _this = $(this);
    var url = _this.attr("data-url");
    var rating = _this.attr("data-rating");
    var storeId = _this.attr("data-store-id");
    var content = $("#ratingTextarea")[0].value;

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val(),
        rating: rating,
        content: content,
        storeId: storeId
      },
      success: function(res) {
        console.log(res);
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can isolate your reviews loop in a separate template:

**reviews.html**

```
{% for i in store.review_set.all %}
  ...
{% endfor %}
```

In your **HTML**:

```
{% include "reviews.html" %}
```

In your **views.py**, you can re-render and return your reviews template as HTML:

```
import json
from django.template import loader
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse
...
reviews_html = loader.render_to_string('reviews.html', context={'store': store})
return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'reviews_html': reviews_html}))
```

Then, in your **Ajax** success method:

```
  success: function(json) {
      // change your reviews div HTML to json['reviews_html'];
  }
```

Comment: Can you change `'reviews_html': reviews_html` to `{'reviews_html': reviews_html}`? Thank you for the help!